# Generating letters of the english alphabet

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have homework due that states that I need to write a program that generates the first 15 letters of the english alphabet. I can't delcare and set 15 different variables or constants. The letters must be displayed in a number of columns initially set by the user. the numbers have to be aligned in columns. Can anyone help? Maximum number of columns is 7 and the minimum is 1.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some pseudo-code to get you started. Read it, understand it, then try to implement it.

```
get numcols from user
if numcols < 1 or numcols > 7:
    print error and exit

ch = 'a'
for count = 1 to 15:
    output ch followed by space
    add 1 to ch
    if count is an integral multiplier of numcols:
        output newline
    endif
endfor
if numcols is not equal to 3 or 5:
    output newline
endif
```

It's pitched at about the level of your homework (no fancy stuff and the smallest hint of awkwardness) and should map reasonably well into C code.

As part of this implementation, you should research:

- the fact that character constants like `'a'` are really integers in disguise.
- remainder or modulus (`%`) operators and how/why they are useful here.
- getting user input with `scanf`.
- `putchar` for outputting characters.
- why you have that final `if` statement :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint:

ASCII code of A is 65, B is 66, C is 67 and so on. You can do it in a loop starting from 65 and going on for 15 iterations.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that on my System z and it just produced garbage :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Wrap that garbage in a beautiful gift box and send it over to me. I will inspect it and reform it into its non-garbage equivalent :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with two nested loops, one for the vertical and one for the horizontal. since the numbers are in sequence in value you can increment the variable for the character each time.

I don't want to give away more than that unless another user says I should. I've already given a lot of help and I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

If you feel you need more help I'll try to not give too much but explain more.